# jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST_METHOD in Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery-plugins, jquery

Having trouble with what I thought was a relatively simple jQuery plugin...

The plugin should fetch data from a php script via ajax to add options to a `<select>`.  The ajax request is pretty generic:

```
$.ajax({
  url: o.url,
  type: 'post',
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: '{"method":"getStates", "program":"EXPLORE"}',
  success: function (data, status) {
    console.log("Success!!");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
  },
  error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
  }
});
```

This seems to work fine in Safari.  In Firefox 3.5, the `REQUEST_TYPE` on the server is always 'OPTIONS', and the $_POST data does not appear.  Apache logs the request as type 'OPTIONS':

```
::1 - - [08/Jul/2009:11:43:27 -0500] "OPTIONS sitecodes.php HTTP/1.1" 200 46
```

Why would this ajax call work in Safari, but not Firefox, and how do I fix it for Firefox?

```
Response Headers
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2009 21:22:17 GMT
Server:Apache/2.0.59 (Unix) PHP/5.2.6 DAV/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Content-Length  46
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html

Request Headers
Host    orderform:8888
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  300
Connection  keep-alive
Origin  http://ux.inetu.act.org
Access-Control-Request-Method   POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers  x-requested-with
```

Here is a picture of the Firebug output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the firebug response and request headers. I am not getting any error when I run similar code in Firefox.

Comment: Added header info, and a picture from Firebug.

Comment: Just had this same problem while implementing an embedded webserver. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: If you are looking for a Java JAX-RS solutions, see here: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Access-Control-Allow-Origin-td6060693.html#a6211931)

Comment: The behavior of firefox seems to have changed now? I don't get any option requests.

Comment: When the response header contains "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type", i got an OPTIONS request and then a POST request.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The reason for the error is the same origin policy. It only allows you to do XMLHTTPRequests to your own domain. See if you can use a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) callback instead:

```
$.getJSON( 'http://<url>/api.php?callback=?', function ( data ) { alert ( data ); } );
```

Comment: Note: See this http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29 for info on using JSONP. You will need the additional "=?" in your query string to trigger JSONP

Comment: why is firefox the only browser to do this? I want a post not a get.

Comment: $.getScript should be possible cross-domain, see http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getScript (but it is not for me in FF 3.6)

Comment: Crossite-POST: Does anybody know a solution to do a POST with application/json as Content-Type?

Comment: So what exactly is the solution?

Comment: Looking for a solution to this too and using getJSON instead of ajax call doesn't do it for me as it's much more limited.

Comment: @schoetbi for that you are going to need to use CORS, which is well supported in newer browsers... limited support in IE8-9, and needs server-side support.

Comment: @schoetbi $.ajax with option `content-type: "application/json"`, and the server response header contains "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type", i got an OPTIONS request and a POST request, still looking for why

Answer (score 57):

I used the following code on Django side to interpret the OPTIONS request and to set the required Access-Control headers. After this my cross domain requests from Firefox started working. As said before, the browser first sends the OPTIONS request and then immediately after that the POST/GET

```
def send_data(request):
    if request.method == "OPTIONS": 
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        response['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 1000
        # note that '*' is not valid for Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept'
        return response
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
```

Edit: it seems to be that at least in some cases you also need to add the same Access-Control headers to the actual response. This can be a little bit confusing, since the request seems to succeed, but Firefox does not pass the contents of the response to the Javascript.

Comment: Your edit about the actual POST/GET response is a bit scary; if anyone can confirm that, then please let us know here!

Comment: I don't know if it is as bug or a feature, but seems to be that somebody else has noticed it as well. See for example http://kodemaniak.de/?p=62 and search for "empty response body"

Comment: There's a difference between simple requests and those that need preflight. Your "solution" will only work with preflight requests, so it's no real solution. Whenever you get an "Origin:"-header in the request headers, you should reply with that being allowed.

Comment: I believe the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should contain the value `x-csrf-token`, not `x-csrftoken`.

Answer (score 17):

This  [mozilla developer center article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) describes various cross-domain request scenarios. The article seems to indicate that a POST request with content type of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' should be sent as a 'simple request' (with no 'preflight' OPTIONS request). I found , however, that Firefox sent the OPTIONS request, even though my POST was sent with that content type.

I was able to make this work by creating an options request handler on the server, that set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header to '*'. You can be more restrictive by setting it to something specific, like 'http://someurl.com'. Also, I have read that, supposedly, you can specify a comma-separated list of multiple origins, but I couldn't get this to work.

Once Firefox receives the response to the OPTIONS request with an acceptable 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value, it sends the POST request.

Comment: Note: Access-Control-Allow-Origin can have only one value (you can't use a comma-separated list), however you can write (or use) a plugin that will programmatically change it to allow different values.

Answer (score 15):

I've fixed this issue using an entirely-Apache based solution.  In my vhost / htaccess I put the following block:

```
# enable cross domain access control
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"

# force apache to return 200 without executing my scripts
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```

You may not need the latter part, depending on what happens when Apache executes your target script.  Credit goes to the [friendly ServerFault folk](https://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests) for the latter part.

Comment: Your answer helped me, but if need some logic behind CORS, it doesn't solve completely.

Answer (score 10):

This PHP at the top of the responding script seems to work.  (With Firefox 3.6.11.  I have not yet done a lot of testing.)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS', $_SERVER)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '
           . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']);
} else {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
}

if("OPTIONS" == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This might be a matter of taste, but *always* sending those response headers (also for `GET`, `POST`, ...) is a bit too much to my liking. (And, I wonder if always sending those complies with the specs?)

Comment: wrap it in  if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']).  If that header is there, it's an CORS-request, if not, well, no need to send anything.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem with sending requests to google maps, and solution is quite simple with jQuery 1.5 - for dataType use `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: Incompatible with method POST.

Comment: It works with a GET method but it's a very limited solution. For example, by doing so you can't send back a response with a specific header including a token.

Answer (score 7):

Culprit is preflight request using OPTIONS method

For HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.

Web specification refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

I resolved the problem by adding following lines in Nginx conf.

```
    location / {
               if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
                   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "*";
                   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, OPTIONS";
                   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
                   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  "true";
                   add_header Content-Length 0;
                   add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                   return 200;
               }
    location ~ ^/(xxxx)$ {
                if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ / last;
                }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful thanks. The fact that the browser is sending a preflight request with an OPTIONS method is non-obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking through source 1.3.2, when using JSONP, the request is made by building a SCRIPT element dynamically, which gets past the browsers Same-domain policy. Naturally, you can't make a POST request using a SCRIPT element, the browser would fetch the result using GET.

As you are requesting a JSONP call, the SCRIPT element is not generated, because it only does this when the Type of AJAX call is set to GET.

http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4690

Answer (score 4):

We had a problem like this with ASP.Net. Our IIS was returning an Internal Server Error when trying to execute a jQuery `$.post` to get some html content due to PageHandlerFactory was restricted to respond only `GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG` Verbs. So you can change that restriction adding the verb "OPTIONS" to the list or selecting "All Verbs"

You can modify that in your IIS Manager, selecting your website, then selecting Handler Mappings, double click in your PageHandlerFactory for *.apx files as you need (We use Integrated application pool with framework 4.0). Click on Request Restrictions, then go to Verbs Tabn and apply your modification.

Now our `$.post` request is working as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

I seems that if `o.url = 'index.php'` and this file exists is ok and returning a success message in the console. It returns an error if I use url:`http://www.google.com`

If doing a post request why not using directly the [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) method:

```
$.post("test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" },
    function(data){
        alert(data.name); // John
        console.log(data.time); //  2pm
    }, "json");
```

It is so much simpler.

Comment: Got the same thing with this...thought I should use $.ajax() so I could at least get some debug info on the error condition..

Answer (score 2):

Check if your form's `action` URL includes the `www` part of the domain, while the original page you have opened is viewed without `www`.

Typically done for Canonical Urls..

I struggled for hours before stumbling upon this article and found the hint of Cross Domain.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to circumvent the problem is to use a proxy script. That method is described for [example here](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this is:

1. use dataType: `json`
2. add `&callback=?` to your url

this worked on calling Facebook API and with Firefox. Firebug is using `GET` instead of `OPTIONS` with the above conditions (both of them).

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a clear example of how to solve this if control the server code of the domain you are POSTing to.  This answer is touched on in this thread, but this more clearly explains it IMO.

[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript/7605119#7605119)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this without

`contentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option:

dataType: "json"

Comment: that worked, why json is considered "safe" for cross-domain requests?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with trying to use the Facebook API.

The only contentType which didn't send the Preflighted request seemed to be just text/plain... not the rest of the parameters mentioned at mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)

- Why is this the only browser which does this?
- Why doesn't Facebook know and accept the preflight request?

FYI: The aforementioned Moz doc suggests X-Lori headers should trigger a Preflighted request ... it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function test_success(page,name,id,divname,str)
{ 
 var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById(name).selectedIndex;
 var dropdownValue = document.getElementById(name)[dropdownIndex].value;
 var params='&'+id+'='+dropdownValue+'&'+str;
 //makerequest_sp(url, params, divid1);

 $.ajax({
    url: page,
    type: "post",
    data: params,
    // callback handler that will be called on success
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML = response;

        var retname = 'n_district';
        var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById(retname).selectedIndex;
        var dropdownValue = document.getElementById(retname)[dropdownIndex].value;
        if(dropdownValue >0)
        {
            //alert(dropdownValue);
            document.getElementById('inputname').value = dropdownValue;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('inputname').value = "00";
        }
        return;
        url2=page2; 
        var params2 = parrams2+'&';
        makerequest_sp(url2, params2, divid2);

     }
});         
}
```

Comment: The question was already answered 6 months ago. How does this solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some work on server side. I see you are using PHP on server side, but solution for .NET web application is here:
[Cannot set content-type to 'application/json' in jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754767/cannot-set-content-type-to-application-json-in-jquery-ajax/18740041#18740041)

Do the same in PHP script and it will work. Simply: At first request browser is asking server if is allowed to send such data with such type and second request is the proper/allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following:

```
dataType: "json",
ContentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({"method":"getStates", "program":"EXPLORE"}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a proxy url to solve a similar problem when I want to post data to my apache solr hosted in another server. (This may not be the perfect answer but it solves my problem.)

Follow this URL: [Using Mode-Rewrite for proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html"), I add this line to my httpd.conf:

```
 RewriteRule ^solr/(.*)$ http://ip:8983/solr$1 [P]
```

Therefore, I can just post data to /solr instead of posting data to http://ip:8983/solr/*. Then it will be posting data in the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

I already have this code handling well my cors situation in php:

```
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.CMSConfig::ALLOW_DOMAIN );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '.CMSConfig::ALLOW_DOMAIN );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
```

And it was working fine locally and remotely, but not for uploads when remote.

Something happen with apache/php OR my code, I didn't bother to search it, when you request OPTIONS it returns my header with cors rules but with 302 result. Therefore my browser doesn't recognise as an acceptable situation.

What I did, based on @Mark McDonald answer, is just put this code after my header:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS' )
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted");
    exit;
}
```

Now, when requesting `OPTIONS` it will just send the header and 202 result.

Answer (score -1):

Please be advised:

**JSONP supports only the GET request method.**

*Send request by *firefox*:*

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',//<<===
   contentType: 'application/json',
   url: url,
   dataType: "json"//<<=============
    ...
});
```

Above request send by **OPTIONS**(while ==>***type: 'POST'***)!!!!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',//<<===
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp"//<<==============
    ...
});
```

But above request send by **GET**(while ==>***type: 'POST'***)!!!!

*When you are in "cross-domain communication" , pay attention and be careful.*