# Google App Engine + jQuery Ajax = 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

Someone has to be able to explain what I'm doing wrong here! I'm trying to create the MOST simple example of an AJAX post to a Google App Engine app...and I'm failing!

Here is the app python

---

```
import cgi

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from django.utils import simplejson

class EmailItem(db.Model):
  email = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class EmailList(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):   
    self.response.out.write("You see nothing!")

  def post(self):
    eitem = EmailItem()
    eitem.email = self.request.get("address")
    eitem.put()
    self.response.out.write("success")


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', EmailList)])
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here's the jQuery

---

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myappengineURL",
        data: "address=" + sVerifiedEmail,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        },
    });
```

Assuming I actually know how to use jQuery and invoke that AJAX call...why do I keep getting a 405 Error?

I've re-written this thing six different ways trying to make it work...and I can't! So far I'm looking at advice from http://blog.pythoughts.com/posts/AJAX-with-Google-App-Engine#jqueryAjax and Google code's AJAX RPC article that I can't post a link to because StackOverflow says NO NO NO. Neither of these examples seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that the post without javascript works? If it does, is your ajax posting to the same url and passing the same data?

Comment: You have an extra comma on line 7 of your jQuery snippet, which may cause the Javascript to fail depending on which browser you're using.

Comment: Yes, the extra comma was a mistake during my paste.

Comment: I can confirm that the post works without javascript...I've tried it with everything in page (much like the google example).

Comment: Is there some kind of security on the App Engine side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is known as "same origin policy". This is why you see the OPTIONS method in your log. The domain and protocol of your Ajax request must be the same as the one you are launching it from.

[Here's the same question with good answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-requestmethod-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3):

I've incorporated jQuery into the [Google App Engine AJAX example](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html). Replace their doAdd() and custom AJAX javascript with:

```
<script language="javascript" src="./static/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="./static/json2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function doAdd()
    // Requests server to add two numbers, loads server response to result
    {
        $.get(
            '/rpc', 
             {"action" : "Add", 
             "arg0" : JSON.stringify($("#num1").val()), 
             "arg1" : JSON.stringify($("#num2").val())}, 
            function(response) { $('#result').val(JSON.parse(response)); }
            );
    }
</script>
```

Works for me!  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myappengineURL",
        data: ({address : sVerifiedEmail}),
        success: function(msg) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        },
    });
```

What happens when you structure your call like I have above?

Comment: Same thing...405 method not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your logs on App Engine. What
  method is being specified, and what's
  the URL?
- Try a POST with Curl or
  Wget. Does that work?

Comment: Doesn't work with a POST. I can't share the URL at the moment...I'll try to set up a dummy site.

Comment: This is an odd log item??

24.251.73.63 - - [17/Aug/2009:22:43:59 -0700] "OPTIONS /add HTTP/1.1" 405 124 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2,gzip(gfe)"

what's the gzip(gfe) doing in there?

Comment: gzip(gfe) is added by the infrastructure. But note the method - 'OPTIONS'. Something you're doing is trying to use the OPTIONS method, which you haven't defined on your class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', EmailList)])

try:
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', EmailList)])

Also, doesn't the data parameter in JS need to be a dictionary? like:
var data = {'email': $F('email_field_name')}

Answer (score -1):

All the other answers were stupid.

You want post instead of get. That should say:

```
class EmailList(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):   
    self.response.out.write("You see nothing!")
```

Comment: !(This is a brilliant answer! +1)