# jQuery: I get OPTIONS request instead of GET

Tags: jquery

I am using simple jQuery

```
$.get( .... );
```

Here instead of getting GET response I get OPTIONS.( checked in firebug Net)

Same code is working fine in Safari. Looks like some problem with Firefox.

Any workaround / solutions to fix this problem..

Thanks

Kurund

Comment: Is the URL you're making the request to on the same domain as your page, or is this cross-domain?

Comment: That's... incredibly strange. How about a minimal test case so we have a hope of figuring out what's going on?

Comment: my ajax request url is http://example.org/ajaxrequest.

So if I call it in  http://example.org domain it works fine else GET gets converted to OPTIONS

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request

Comment: Do you have control over the target resource? In particular, can you add headers to the HTTP response?

Comment: looks like cross-domain issue and can't find any workaround for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps someone:
http://kurund.com/blog/2010/09/09/how-to-call-external-site-url-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: This doesn't work when your setting custom headers as the jsonp script can't get executed.

Answer (score 28):

The `OPTIONS` request what you see is the preflight request, you can read about that here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control
- http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(VS.85).aspx

It's there because you're requesting a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest so the browser has to check whether your request is allowed on the remote server or not.

There are two solutions to solve the problem (as mentioned above):

- implement the response for the `OPTIONS` request with the corresponding `Access-Control-*` headers
- use a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) request instead of simple JSON

Comment: That seems to be my case. But how would I implement the response for the OPTION request? Where should I implement it? My WebMethod doesn't even get called. Do I need to override something?

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm not familiar with .NET but maybe this article could help you: http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Comment: I have to say the cross-domain behaviour of 'modern' browsers is getting ridiculous. If you have a server like couchdb which sends Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * but doesn't implement OPTIONS you can't do a simple AJAX GET because the browser decides to 'check' first and break everything. The developer knows the GET will work but the browser doesn't believe them!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to restrictions on Javascript doing cross-domain XMLHttpRequests.  This is generally not allowed for security reasons.  See the question referenced above, or a [similar question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-requestmethod-in-firefox).

To solve this problem:

- Write a sever side component (using PHP or whatever) that will retrieve the remote resource on behalf of your AJAX request, or
- Do a JSONP call: see http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html (or hunt around StackOverflow for JSONP)  :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the cause I figured was in the html `<head>` section I had set the base element to this

```
<base href="http://local.develepment.url" />
```

Which I changed to

```
<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request to **cross domain**.

> For **cross-domain** requests, setting the content type to anything other
>   than **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, **multipart/form-data**, or
>   **text/plain** will trigger the browser to send a **preflight OPTIONS**
>   request to the server.

So you may need change specify **contentType** to avoid OPTION request.
Example:-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "crossdomainurl",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'text/plain'
});
```