# Make Tweet Button work on Https Page

Tags: ssl, twitter, authentication, https, login-script

I'm admittedly new to SSL.  My impression is that all of the files that hit the given page must come from secure sources.  All my image and js files are being rerouted through https.

Is that accurate?

I want to login a user on a splash page that also contains a facebook like and tweet button. The tweet button is written for http and, when I tried to alter the protocol, it stopped working.

How can I get around this?

Comment: why you need the button to be on https?

Comment: I have a splash page for my private Beta. The page includes some Ajax that allows users to login on that page. At first, I tried to send the login form to an https action, but that didn't work easily so I figured this route would be best

Comment: this post is kind of a companion piece, you'll get a better sense of what I mean.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784842/django-secure-login-with-ajax-from-http-page

Comment: +1, facing the same frustrating issue.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has an [FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#https) on this. Basically they recommend [building your own](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#build-your-own) HTML tweet button. The downside is there will be no total share count displayed.

You could theoretically download all the JS that is used in the tweet button and host them on your own site but if Twitter changes how any of the APIs it uses your implementation would break. You would also likely have to modify the JS files to get them to make the count request over SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has already added SSL-support.

You can include their library like this:
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/ssl-support-tweet-button-and-follow-button

Answer (score 0):

This guy has a solution that worked for me: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/create_a_https_twitter_tweet_button_for_your_web_page_or_blog24?lang=en

I preferred to just use javascript to grab the current page, so in his example, I bypassed the part where a url is passed to twitterPop() and added this line to the beginning of that function:

```
    str=document.URL;
```

There's no counter but it's better than nothing!