# jquery: why $.get send OPTION packet?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.get('http://localhost/a.bb?cmd=<abc></abc>', function(data) {
   alert('result comes back.');
   $('.result').html(data);
  });
);
```

Above is the code I want send to server, why jquery send OPTION for me? I want GET method.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST_METHOD in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery/webbrowser will send a [HTTP `OPTIONS`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2) request whenever the URL concerns a different domain than the one from which the inital page is been requested and the jQuery `dataType` is not `JSONP`. On an `OPTIONS` request, the server should return an [`Allow` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.7) with all HTTP methods which are allowed to be used. E.g. `GET,POST`. The webbrowser will then continue the *actual* XMLHttpRequest.

This all is in the name of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

this probably coming from your browser, or the way you format your get request it my be safer to pass the data as

```
$.get('http://localhost/a.bb',{"cmd":"<abc></abc>"}, function(data) {
        alert('result comes back.');
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
);
```