# Same domain JQuery $.ajax sending OPTIONS as REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain

My problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox) but I don't see why my requests would be cross-domain.
Here is what I get with firebug:

[image: domain is same but request method is OPTIONS]

All domains are the same, I don't understand why Firefox and IE have this behaviour.

You can test [here](http://tronatic-production.com/v3/en/), just click on one of the three main links to send a request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just about the domain name.  The protocol (http vs. https) has to be the same, the entire host name has to be the same, and the port has to be the same. Some of your links are to "www.tronatic-production.com", but the page loads with just "tronatic-production.com".

[Here](http://alexsexton.com/?p=154) is a presentation from noted JavaScript expert and hipster *extraordinaire* Alex Sexton about the Same Origin Policy and ways to deal with it.

*edit* The reason that your links have "www" prepended is that you've got a `<base>` tag in your header that's telling the browser to do exactly that.

Comment: Oh thanks you're right! But why my links target url with "www" even if base url doesn't contain it?

Comment: I don't know; let me do a quick "view source".