# OPTION Preflight to stackexchange api responds with BAD REQUEST

Tags: stackexchange-api, preflight, http-options-method

I've been banging my head against this all day. When trying to post to stackexchange from my webapp, I keep getting a 400 BAD REQUEST on my request. I've been using fiddler to try and spoof requests but I can't seem to get it to go through. Would anyone know what the cause is, and how I should form my request?

Example request

```
OPTIONS https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/32262145/upvote?filter=default&key=9Gn[..the rest of key..]jMF*Q((&site=stackoverflow HTTP/1.1
Host: api.stackexchange.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: [my site]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: [the page on my site]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2015 

01:23:39 GMT
Content-Length: 95
```

With JSON

```
JSON
  error_id=404
  error_message=this method cannot be called this way
  error_name=no_method
```

Comment: I think a query parameter can't contain brackets. Maybe urlencoding the params would help?

Comment: My apologies. That's just me redacting my website address and my key since this is a public forum.

Comment: the `*Q((` part as well?

Comment: Oh. No. When spoofing with fiddler, I've tried removing the query string and I still get the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request method is OPTIONS instead of post (existing StackExchange post doens't help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855490/request-method-is-options-instead-of-post-existing-stackexchange-post-doenst-h)