# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf, rest

I have read many similar problems in StackOverflow, but the solutions doesn't work for me.

I have WCF REST service:

```
[<OperationContract>]    
    [<WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "PostItem", 
            RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,   
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")>]
```

I can use it using Postman (Chrome extension). I am passing data as 'raw', not 'urlencoded'.  And I get 200 return code.

[image]

I need to call this method using angularjs:

```
    $http.post('http://192.168.1.65/Service1.svc/restapi/PostItem',                   
                {
    "Address": "г. Москва, ул. Соколово-Мещерская, д.25",
     ...
    "User": ""
      })
```

I have just copied URL and JSON from Postman.  But I get the error:

> angular.js:10722 OPTIONS
>   http://192.168.1.65/Service1.svc/restapi/PostItem
>   http://192.168.1.65/Service1.svc/restapi/PostItem. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

I have searched similar problems and have found two solutions:

1. Use jQuery to set header `Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`, but it doesn't work with my WCF service
2. Set custom headers in my Web.Config:

   ```
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   ```

It doesn't help me. And I am not sure that the reason of the error on the server side.  The Postman extension can call this method succesfully.

How can I make the same POST call using AngularJS ?

**Update**:

Here is OPTIONS request:

[image]

Review and Response tabs are empty

**Update 2:**

All works fine in IE, but doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: usually .Net will send error information along with its 405 status code... did you get any?

Comment: i have updated my question and add screen of this request in Chrome.

Comment: no, see in the update image you posted, check the "preview" tab

Comment: Preview and Response tabs are empty

Comment: try setting all parameters in our WCF function to optional.  Let me know what that does

Comment: I have the same error. I have tried to attach VS to IIS and debug the code, but my method even was called from Angular application

Comment: To me 405 is invalid method : mean you could call POST instead of GET (or reverse) - but that doesn't seem so obvious in your code

Comment: I have found that this code works in IE, but doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: @ScottSelby, I have found solution. Look at my answer.  May be you have some comments or additions, because for me it looks like unfair hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I have found solution.  I just added second method:

```
[<OperationContract>]    
[<WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "PostTest", 
        RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,   
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")>]         
abstract PostTest: obj: Test -> unit

[<OperationContract>]    
[<WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "PostTest", 
        RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,   
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "OPTIONS")>]         
abstract PostTestOptions: unit -> unit
```

It is just empty methods that do nothing. I don't know the reason, but all is working.

Comment: It worked because you already have customHeaders in your web.config that returns what COR expect, but you didn't have a uriTemplate that allowed OPTIONS. So, after you created an emtpy method, the preflight could work and it got the excpected headers from customHeaders.

Comment: This works, but I think you can just change the existing method to Method = "OPTIONS" without duplicating it. It will still post data.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me, was scratching my head for ages. See my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449208/response-from-pre-flight-failing-with-status-405/48460836#48460836
I tried with just Method=OPTIONS and this failed

Answer (score 25):

I want to show what work for me.

First you must **enable CORS** on `web.config` (like Mihai sad):

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,     OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

If you have some extra HEADER parameter, you must add it to Access-Control-Allow-Headers, like:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, X-Your-Extra-Header-Key" />
```

And finally, to handle OPTIONS requests you must reply with empty response, adding in your application class:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting the same error in ASP net web api 4. what to do please suggest

Comment: I got it sometimes when some dll file are corrupted. Do you have a way to test if the server are returnig something? It happen in every call you made or just in some cases?

Comment: simple $.ajax call are working fine but when making the request from $http (angularjs module) its giving this error.. I have posted a question on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629422/angularjs-with-asp-net-web-api-http-post-returning-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load?noredirect=1#comment62740684_37629422

Comment: The flushing worked for me (upvoted accordingly) but I do not understand why. My JQuery Ajax calls work OK without this, when on a mobile device but running in VisualStudio I get 405 from the same JQuery call. What does the flush do exactly and why do I need it?

Answer (score 2):

Although this already has an answer, but heres my solution.
In the web config you have to remove the instruction to `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />`

First add in the customHeaders

```
<httpProtocol>
  <!-- THESE HEADERS ARE IMPORTANT TO WORK WITH CORS -->
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, X-Authentication, name" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Then either comment out or delete the instruction to remove the OPTIONSverbHandler

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <!-- <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> -->
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since IIS Team published [IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) hacks like empty methods are not needed anymore. It deals with CORS including preflight requests properly. You can configure it in the web config for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="*" />
            <add origin="https://*.microsoft.com"
                 allowCredentials="true"
                 maxAge="120"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                    <add header="header1" />
                    <add header="header2" />
                </allowHeaders>
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="DELETE" />
                </allowMethods>
                <exposeHeaders>
                    <add header="header1" />
                    <add header="header2" />
                </exposeHeaders>
            </add>
            <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the same problem with deleting `xhr.setRequestHeader()` in my AJAX request. If someone has one in code, try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Add this to web.config (server-side):

   ```
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,  OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   ```
2. Create a Global.asax file (Global application class) and add the following code:

   ```
       protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
           if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
               {
                   Response.Flush();
               }
       }
   ```

Comment: It is a working solution and there is no need to downvote it only because that it does not look good.