# Http 405 on Chrome and FF on POST WS call

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services, rest

This is my WS :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]FichierDwgDTO fichierDwgDTO)
    {...}
```

And I call it in my angular app :

```
var res = self.$http.post('http://localhost:52087/api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson', msgdata);
```

It's working with IE(11), but with chrome and FF i get a http 405 error, saying :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:52087/api/Schema/convertDwgEnJson. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514687/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-405)

Comment: You must enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).