# AngularJS With Asp.net Web API: $http post returning XMLHttpRequest cannot load: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When trying to POST json to Asp.net web API server using `$http` it's returning the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62158/api/video/add.
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

but making the same request from `$.ajax` is working file.

**$HTTP Code**

```
$http.post(url, data, config)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defered.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        defered.reject(data);
    });
```

**$.ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: newVideo,
    success: function (a) {
         debugger;
    },
    error: function (e) {
       debugger;
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

**asp.net web api code and configuration**

**web.config**

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,     OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );


    VideoLIbraryDb.Config.setconnection();

    var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

    formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));


}
```

**API controller**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/video")]
    public class VideoController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("add")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage add([FromBody] db_videos newVideo)
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            CommonResult result = new CommonResult() /// default
            {
                code = ResultCodes.retry.ToString(),
                message = "Not able to complete request. Retry."
            };

            if (newVideo.video_file_name == null)
                return Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, result);

            if (newVideo.video_file_name.Length < 1)
                return Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, result);


            if (newVideo.insert())
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                result.code = ResultCodes.successfull.ToString();
                result.message = "Video is added";
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: apply cors on backend side

Comment: no idea how to do it. Please guide @Rakeschand

Comment: it's a cors issue and needs to be solved from backend asp.net side. you can search for it. I don't know asp as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**@Rakeschand** you were right and it was the issue of **cors**

**Cors**

I installed Cors in my project using nu-get command line

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

and added the follwoing code in WebApiConfig.cs file from App_Start folder.

```
var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                               "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                               "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

and removed the following from the web config

```
   <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Content-Type, Origin" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

$http started working just like the `$.ajax` was working

**but these things left me with some confusion. I would be great full if anyone can elaborate**

1. why the `$.ajax` was working and `$http` was not working
2. I did the same thing by `cors` the I had done in `web.config` then why did `cors` worked but `web.config` didn't?

Comment: I ran into the same problem and this resolved it for me. I would love to understand why the web.config didn't work.

Comment: Why web.config did not work out? Can someone please explain.

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks @William for answering.

Comment: @Vikas OMG man, thank you so much. I have been trying to fix this for 4 hours with web.config setup, and it wasn't working. Thank you so much <3

Comment: @Kadaj Welcome brother

Comment: @VikasBansal, do u have some knowledge now that why $.http won't work and $.ajax works with only chang in config file?

Comment: no @SmitPatel , in case you get an idea please let us know :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you must set the content-type on your ajax call:

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
```

or

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```