# AngularJS - $http.post send data as json not working

Tags: angularjs, http, post

The service works when i am not sending any data or if i am sending data as url params. When i am trying to send data as post params the response status code is 405 (method not allowed). Below is the AngularJS service method that i am using.

```
this.editAuthUser = function (url) {
    var data = { email: 'abc@xyz.com', username: 'test'};       
    return $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
        data: data
    });
};
```

I am sharing the image of the headers as displayed in developer tools. [image: headers_img]

Comment: This might be a server side problem. As a test, try removing the headers from your $http request and check if you get something on that route

Comment: I removed them its still not working. I tested this service in POSTMAN app and it was working.

Comment: What is the url for that request? Are you getting any 'Cross origin requests' errors in console?

Comment: In console i am getting this XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.152.19.207/DataAnalysis/ProductService.svc/UpdateUserData. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Take a look at this.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514687/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-405

Comment: Okay i am checking this link and will make changes on the serverside and let you know. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of web method you are trying to hit to?