# Posting data to REST API (coded in Ruby/Sinatra platform) using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby, rest, rubygems, sinatra

I have developed a simple REST API in Ruby/Sinatra platform. The API is working fine when I am posting data through REST Client, Firefox extension. Here is my code of API

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/json'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'
configure do
  enable :cross_origin
end
set :environment, :production
post '/test' do
 cross_origin :allow_origin => '*',
    :allow_methods => [:post],
    :allow_credentials => true,
    :max_age => "60"
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  aFile = File.new("data/data.json", "w+")
if aFile
   aFile.syswrite(data)
end
  json data
end


get '/test' do
   cross_origin :allow_origin => '*',
    :allow_methods => [:get],
    :allow_credentials => true,
    :max_age => "60"
  aFile = File.new("data/data.json", "r+")
if aFile
  content = aFile.sysread(100)
end
  json content
end
```

This Ruby code is running on local server at port 4567. Now When I am trying to post data from jquery then I am getting 404 error. Here is my jquery code.

```
var prospect_id=5;
var customer_id=10;
var page=  window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
var dataString='{"prospect_id" : "'+prospect_id+'", "c_id" : "'+customer_id+'", "page" : "'+page+'"}';
var url = "http://localhost:4567/test";
$.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: url,  
       data:JSON.stringify(dataString),  
       success: function(msg){
                             var obj=JSON.parse(msg);
                            alert(obj);
                            }
            });
```

I am getting following error in javascript console.

```
 OPTIONS http://localhost:4567/test 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:29
    OPTIONS http://localhost:4567/test Invalid HTTP status code 404 jquery.min.js:29
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4567/test. Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

The message in cmd from where I am running my Ruby Code

"OPTIONS/test HTTP/1.1" 404 445 (when I am posting through jquery)
"POST/test HTTP/1.1" 200 61 (when I am posting thhrough REST Client Browser Extension)

The dirrence between two request is OPTIONS AND POST. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is cross-origin POST.

There are different ways to solve it:

[jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST_METHOD in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox) 
use a JSONP callback

or

[jQuery.ajax sending both OPTIONS and POST, how to handle with Express.js (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689986/jquery-ajax-sending-both-options-and-post-how-to-handle-with-express-js-node-j) response for OPTIONS request

The example is for node.js but you can adapt this for sinatra.