# CORS - OPTIONS ... 404 (not found)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, cors

Hi I'm having a problem with CORS.

**GENERAL STRUCTURE:**

Angular 4 sends data of a Form to my api.
Function `saveForm()` is executed when I send information about form contact.

***app.component.ts***

```
saveForm() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    // Encode JSON as string to exchange data to web server.
    this.data = JSON.stringify(this.myContact);

    this.http.post('https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api', this.data, requestOptions).subscribe(res => {
            let result = res.json();
            if(result['result'] == 'success') {
                this.successMessage = true;
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Here is the root of problem, because I'm using `POST` and `Content-Type->application/json` to send my data and by definition It gives me a problem with `CORS` - `preflighted request`, here more definition: [Link about preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

This meaning that before angular 4 sends the data to the server, this asks to server if it is available to receive my data with the verb `OPTION`, if the response of server is OK then angular 4 sends the data of form.

**PROBLEM:**

In console I always get this error message:

> OPTIONS https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api 404 (Not Found)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://pablocordova.herokuapp.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>
> XHR failed loading: POST
>   "https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api".
>
> ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false,
>   statusText: "", headers: Headers…}

**WHAT I TRIED:**

so far, I understand that problem is because `https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api` doesn't return answer for verb `OPTIONS`

then I tried to resolve this of 2 ways:

***Using cors package*** [CORS package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)
I configured according documentation.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
...
var app = express();
...
app.options('/api', cors());
app.post('/api', cors(), function(req, res, next) {

    // Proccess to send this data via email
    // and also save in data base(only for learning)

});
```

But I get in console the same error.

***Configuring headers manually by*** [Discussion StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689986/jquery-ajax-sending-both-options-and-post-how-to-handle-with-express-js-node-j) or [Discussion Github](https://gist.github.com/nilcolor/816580)

That code is inserted inside every route that I want to write the headers, in my case:

```
app.post('/api', function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
          console.log('!OPTIONS');
          var headers = {};
          // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
          // headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
          headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
          headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
          headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
          headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
          headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept";
          res.writeHead(200, headers);
          res.end();
    } else {
        // Process to send this data via email
        // and also save in data base(only for learning)
    } 

});
```

Here the problem is that never execute `console.log('!OPTIONS');`

Here also I tried simply:

```
app.post('/api', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('!I AM YOUR FATHER');
    ...
});
```

but never is printed.
Note: I tried to see this message with `heroku logs` because the whole page is in Heroku.

But also doing this I get the same error.

**MORE INFORMATION:**

When the `.../api` is called, I have this headers

```
**GENERAL**:

Request URL:https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:23.21.185.158:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**RESPONSE HEADERS**:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Cowboy
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 04:14:45 GMT
Content-Length: 494
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

**REQUEST HEADERS**:

OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1
Host: pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://pablocordova.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: https://pablocordova.herokuapp.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
```

***QUESTION:***

That is my true problem or I am understanding bad? **and/or**
What can I do to solve that problem? **and/or** 
Any advices?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow Very detailed research you had made. 

But you a missing a main problem. the Response status code. Which is 404. 

Please verify if your endpoint URL is correct. !

Comment: Thanks, I can´t believe that I didn't realize the endpoint URL was wrong, thanks!

Comment: Most of the times the problems will be a minor typo and we would considered all the super duper scenarios. But that is how we keep learning. Keep Learning.. Kudos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be: https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api *always* returns 404:

```
$ curl -i https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

That is, the server isn’t doing anything special/different for the `OPTIONS` request — instead all requests are just hitting that 404.

> ```
> app.post('/api', function(req, res, next) {
>     console.log('!I AM YOUR FATHER');
>     ...
> });
> ```

I’m not super clear on how Express handles this case, but it may be that must configure it to send *some* kind of response for that route — not just a `console.log` on the server side.

When I look at the content of https://pablocordovaupdated.herokuapp.com/api what I see is just a generic Heroku 404 page — so it’s not being served from your app but instead falling back to being served by Heroku. For example, the contents of that 404 page have this:

```
<iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/no-such-app.html"></iframe>
```

That is, it appears to be that request for that URL are never getting handled as expected by your app code at all under any circumstances. So it seems like that’s what you need to fix first.

Comment: Thanks!!! I dont know how I didn't realize of that the true endpoint must be: https://pablocordova.herokuapp.com/api, thanks again I was trying to solve this problem almost for 2 hours.