# jquery ajax delete 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to do a 'DELETE' call on an API for a while and it never worked.
I can access the URI and see the JSON. And I've tried other web services which properly make the DELETE call. On my local machine and on Heroku, I can't get it to work. Any idea what's wrong here?

I've tried adding headers and such.

```
$.ajax({
      url : url,
      type : 'DELETE',
      beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
          },
      crossDomain: true,
      success : function(data) {
        console.log("gone");
      },
      error : function(){
        console.log("ohcrap");
      }
    });
```

Comment: What are the headers that it returns to you in the 404.  You setting crossDomain on your end doesn't matter one bit if that url's server doesn't expose a valid CORS header for you on the preflight options for DELETES.

Comment: The jQuery website states for .ajax that for "type: DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers." What browser are you using?

Comment: By accessing the URI, would imply the route is a GET not a DELETE route. Are you developing the routes as well?  the 404 would validate that most likely there is no DELETE route set up, but the GET route is. Do you have the backend code?

Comment: @NickSharp There may still be an issue with cross domain here, but it wouldn't produce a the 404.

Comment: @BarryTormey I'm using the newest Chrome.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews The backend works fine. I tested it with site such as www.hurl.it and it deleted the entry.

Comment: Do you have any kind of console log info you can post? Response headers, anything like that?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I found out that it's sending a preflight request that's messing it up. The OPTIONS request is getting 404. Does mean sites like Hurl.it skip the preflight?

Comment: Does your route require `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");` or should it be `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` ?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Yup I tried that. It's suppose to skip the OPTIONS preflight but doesn't work. Weird thing is when I requested through ruby it works fine.

Comment: I think this applies to your situation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox

Comment: The OPTIONS preflight is part of the browsers way of CORS checking... so if your server is 404'ing that it won't even be trying the POST/PUT/DELETE etc... the OPTIONS is to get the CORS header back to know if the browser is gonna let you make the DELETE/POST/PUT etc.

Comment: You can use JSONP to do that

Comment: Hey I figured it out. It turned out to be CORS problem from the server. It didn't have preflight setup so Ajax wasn't allowed to make the request, but anything from the server was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be CORS problem from the server. It didn't have preflight setup so Ajax wasn't allowed to make the request, but anything from the server was fine.