# Cross-domain POST using jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, cross-domain

I use cross-domain $.ajax. When I use GET everything is ok, but when I try to send a POST I have some problem.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
});
```

Then:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': another_domain_url,
    'data': data,
    'type': 'post',
    'crossDomain': true,
    ...
});
```

When I use 'type'='get' here — everything is ok. But if I use 'post', I have in Chrome Console:

```
OPTIONS (my_url) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
  l.cors.a.crossDomain.send           jquery.min.js:4
  o.extend.ajax                       jquery.min.js:4
  ...
```

And in the Network tab:

```
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
  Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
  Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

What can I do?

Comment: Wow, I just understood that "OPTIONS" is a method. Why "OPTIONS", when I send "POST"?

Comment: Might be related to the issue you're seeing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox

Comment: OPTIONS is part of what happens when you send a CORS request. what is your dataType?