# DELETE request Ajax in a Floodlight SDN controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sdn

I have a function in my JavaScript that makes an Ajax request to the REST interface of a Floodlight controller.

```
function excluir(nome)
{
    var jsonExclui = ("{" + '"name": "'+nome+'" }');
    alert(jsonExclui);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://192.168.56.99:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json",
        method: "DELETE",
        //  type: 'DELETE',
        data: jsonExclui,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.status);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert("Deu erro : "+data.status);
        }
    });
}
```

The DELETE method is accepted and appears in the SDN controller documentation.

https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1343518

But when analyzing the browser console realized he tells me that I'm sending OPTIONS and not DELETE.

> Remote Address:192.168.56.99:8085  Request URL:'http:192.168.56.99:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json'  Request
>   Method:OPTIONS  Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Accept-Ranges:bytes  Allow:DELETE, POST  Connection:keep-alive 
>   Content-Type:application/json  Date:Thu, 14 May 2015 11:46:43 GMT 
>   Server:Restlet-Framework/2.3.1  Transfer-Encoding:chunked

There is some method to make the browser do not do this pre-request OPTIONS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.ajax(), $.post sending "OPTIONS" as REQUEST\_METHOD in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox)

Comment: it s preflight cors request. setup cors or use jsonp

Comment: When  send whit JSONP, it recognizes the request as GET. Request Method : GET Status Code: 405 Method not allowed.