# Calling web service returning Cancelled status with Method Options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I have a web service, built by third party. I just want to consume it. I am doing this using JQuery as Below.

```
var dwhServiceUrl = 'http://10.62.210.138/DWHWebService/hubservice.asmx/GetHubDetailUser';
            // call segmentation svc
            CallAjaxAsync('POST', SegmentSuccess, '', dwhServiceUrl,
                          {
                              strWSUserName: 'XXX',
                              strWSPassword: 'XXX',
                              strApplicationId: '1',
                              strCompanyId: '1',
                              strRole: 'XXX',
                              strUserID: 'XXX',
                              strOptionList: 'HIGHLIGHT',
                              strFieldName: 'POLICY NO',
                              strFieldValue: '<%=Session["Source_Policy_No"]%>'
                          });
```

Where `CallAjaxAsync` definition is

```
function CallAjaxAsync(type, FuncSuccess, FuncError, url, param) {
    if (param != '') {
        param = JSON.stringify(param)
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: param,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: FuncSuccess,
        error: FuncError,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "apikey:APIKEY,tokenid:4a5ba979-0c56-468d-87c7-30a22759f7ce",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US"
        }
    });
```

But I am not receiving any response. It's status is `Cancelled` and method in `OPTIONS` on Network tab of console.

[image]

Comment: You may need to ask this third party to have CORS enabled or you may need to make the request through a proxy on the same domain as your JS application.  See this related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox).

Comment: @simonl thank you. I will consider your advise

Comment: @simonl I can access that service through browser on my machine, still it is CORS problem?

Comment: Not exactly, what I was referring to was your browser's impl of the cross-origin policy - see (here)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy].  You basically aren't allowed to hit an endpoint that lives on a different domain it's a security feature.  CORS lets you get around this but has to be enabled on the server.  People typically get around this by having a proxy (e.g. Node) server make requests on behalf of your JS app